# print bill through c# .net window application

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have coded one billing software. Now I want to print this bill in specific format. 
I read printDocument and printDialog tools for it. But I have to give x and y axis position for each string or line we draw in printdocument.

Is there any GUI type tool so I can format all fields of bill in their position and just pass data from backend so every time it will print same bill with different value I pass.

Can any one suggest me from where to start.

Comment: Please tell, do you use *Crystal reports* functionality for generation of the receipt? Have you tried using *Crystal reports designer* (which is GUI tool and is embedded into Visual Studio within Crystal reports feature) to specify formatting for your receipt? Please also specify which version and edition of Visual Studio you use and whether you have complete *Crystal reports* functionality (free distributive of Crystal reports is available on [businessobjects](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp) website of SAP)?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this from scratch without any other tools I would leverage HTML (it may be the case you have access to other tools, crystal-reports or SSRS, which would be easier).  HTML is designed specifically for layout design and .NET provides a lot of support for HTML.  (While I have not researched it recently I'm sure there are tools for displaying HTML in an application and sending that to the printer.)

HTML as XML lends itself to templating or you can leverage many of the tools that exist (see Mustache etc.).  .NET has templating built in, but some of the tools available are nicer.

Comment: The approach you have suggested is really helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use localreport(rdlc). check this article on code project:

[Microsoft Reporting without SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25222/Microsoft-Reporting-without-SQL-Server-Reporting-S)

[Microsoft Reporting Services - Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38554/Microsoft-Reporting-Services-Part-II)